# How to organize fixtures when using pytest

Tags: python, fixtures, pytest

Fixtures tend to be small and reusable. Given that a specific fixture can rely on other fixtures

```
@pytest.fixture
def Account(db, memcache):
    ...
```

I would like to organize my fixtures in modules, and import them in a specific test-file like so (e.g.)

```
from .fixtures.models import Account
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. Instead I always have to import all subordinate fixtures too, e.g.

```
from .fixtures.models import Account, db, memcache
```

What is the better approach to have fine-grained small, reusable fixtures and make them accessible on a module level. (conftest works on the package/directory level.)

Comment: What is wrong with organising the fixtures in conftest.py files?  This works fine for us in large projects and they all get loaded and have suitable implicit scoping.

Comment: @flub One issue I have with conftest is when you have many of them at various levels of test directory. To figure out where a fixture came from, you'd have to scan all conftest files from bottom up. Your IDE won't have a clue where it came from.

Comment: `--fixtures --verbose` will tell you were fixtures come from.  also if i'm not mistaken jedi will find the definition of a fixture these days.  someone should probably write this up these comments as a proper answer to this question...

Answer (score 1):

Usually i don't recommend this but if you have modules containing a specific set of fixtures (Which depend on each other), then maybe `from .fixtures.models import *` would be workable?  I can't think of another generic solution at the moment which would avoid knowing the underlying fixture dependencies in the importing test module.

Comment: I actually came from the `from funcargs import *` approach, and tried to avoid it. Worth a _feature request_?

Comment: unless there is an idea how to improve it, a feature request will not be of much help, i am afraid.