# Defining a single conftest.py for tests in subdirectories

Tags: python, pytest

I have an application where my unit tests are organised like so:

```
server/
  tests/
    conftest.py
    test_server.py
client/
  tests/
    conftest.py
    test_client.py
```

In this setup, there's no duplication of fixture config since the `conftest.py` files have fixtures for only their relevant tests.

Now I'm adding integration tests, organised like so:

```
tests/
  conftest.py
  test_integration.py
server/
  tests/
    conftest.py
    test_server.py
client/
  tests/
    conftest.py
    test_client.py
```

This new `conftest.py` needs to have **all** the fixtures I've defined elsewhere. How can I setup py.test such that I avoid duplicating all the fixtures from both `client/tests/conftest.py` and `server/tests/conftest.py`?

The closest similar question is:
[How to organize fixtures when using pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396202/how-to-organize-fixtures-when-using-pytest)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I handle this situation is move all fixtures which are shared to a toplevel conftest file like this:

```
conftest.py
tests/
    [conftest.py]
    test_integration.py
server/
    tests/
        [conftest.py]
        test_server.py
client/
    tests/
        [conftest.py]
        test_client.py
```

This does make it sometimes a bit less nice as you end up with a bunch of not very related fixtures in the toplevel conftest.py, but it is easy and obvious.

Comment: I thought about this, but was hoping for another way.. Thanks flub